# Coherence Weblogic 12 Maven

Tags: maven, weblogic, maven-3, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

I am trying to creating a project from a maven archetype using Coherence

However, when I execute

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.oracle.coherence
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-gar-archetype
-DarchetypeVersion=12.1.2-0-0
-DgroupId=org.mycompany
-DartifactId=my-gar-project
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I recive the following error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.oracle.coherence:maven-gar-archetype:12.1.2-0-0)

Is there some other configuration to use it?

Comment: Seems correct based on: http://www.ateam-oracle.com/new-maven-support-in-fusion-middleware-12-1-2/ and http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/coherence_project.htm The only guess I have is somehow the right jar files aren't in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee that this will solve your problem, but there is a coherence-mock.jar that is shipped in the lib folder, and that was one of the reasons for creating that JAR.

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*